# resizing/moving LVM volumes

Tags: partitioning, centos, lvm

I have a server machine running CentOS 6.2. It is configured using LVM mapping as it is the default and I didn't see any problem with going that way.

I have a 500Gb drive in there right now, and 54Gb is at the root directory, while 442Gb is mounted to /home

Since this is a server, I just started putting all the files I needed to share in /home/sharedFiles and it has been working fine. However, I have run into a bit of an issue... or what I think will be an issue.

I have recently been installing some machines via KVM for experimentation and to have a test machine to make configuration changes to rather than changing the main system(which is, more or less, how I want it, all extra packages removed, etc.) As you may imagine, allocating a 10gb virtual disk to these machines has been eating away at my space. I'd rather not put these in /home since I consider that an OS level thing and not just my files. Is there a way I can move around/extend/shrink the LVM volumes? I actually would actually like most of my main hard drive split up for OS stuff, the Web Server files, and other storage that does not need to be redundant (Install media for Linux distros which are kept there for convenience, etc.) while a RAID array will handle my personal data. Is this kind of configuration possible without taking the system offline for an extended period of time?

EDIT: In fact, I tried to place the KVM images in /home and couldn't, so this is my only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the available space you have, the FS (ext3 I suppose) you have on /home. 
Generally, the idea is:

1. Shrink Filesystem **to** the number of GB you need.
2. Shrink the Logical Volume of the LVM
3. Create a new Logical Volume
4. Format that LV

So, let's go step by step:
All steps executed as root. I assume that your /home is the /dev/mapper/home or /dev/sda2. Use the devices of your case.

1. **Shrink FS**:

   `umount /dev/mapper/home`, or whatever is you /home or `umount /dev/sda2`

   `resize2f2 /dev/sda2 350G`

   350G is the **NEW** size.
2. **Shrink LV**

   Execute as root:

   `lvdisplay`

   It must show you something like the following:

   `LV Name                /dev/system/home`

   This is the logical volume you need to shrink. So, execute:

   `lvreduce -L 350g system/home`

   That will reduce the LV to the correct size.
3. **Create a new LV**

   Now, you have 92GB free. So, let's create a new LV of that size:

   `lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n kvmlv system`

   That command creates a new logical volume named `kvmlv` in the Volume Group `system`.
   You can find your Volume Group either by the `/dev/mapper`, or by the `vgdisplay` command

   Now, you are ready to create you new FS. I would recommend to use ext4.

   `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/system-kvmlv`

Now you are ready to mount it.

Comment: So there's no way to add to the existing \dev\dm-0 (the root partition)?
Like in Windows, I know you can extend a partition if there is free space on the drive. I guess I am looking for something similar to that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want to do, no.

Comment: Ok, assuming it is not possible to do that, is there any way to back up my installation(just the Main OS, config, etc.), reprovision the drive with LVM, then install it just as it is now?
Sorry, I'm kind of new to Linux but trying to learn. I thought this server project would get my feet wet with some of the more advanced admin stuff and eventaully want to start using linux at least 50% of the time on the desktop side.

Comment: I cannot help you very much on that. And the reason is that you have YOUR setup, I have MINE. I do not have a deep knowledge of your system, so, I could say something wrong. In principle, **yes**, you can take a full back and restore everything back. Amanda is a nice backup solution. Depending on what you want to backup (eg just your files, or your /home?) even rsync could be the tool for you.

Comment: I finally figured out how to do it. I just had to take the volume offline, shrink it, then take the other volume offline and grow it to the amount of space the LVM had left. I totally understand not wanting to post something that will screw up someone else's system. Also, about the backup thing, I wanted to backup my actual OS. I have a backup of the files in /home, but I have done enough custom config on this machine that I didn't want to lose it.

Comment: I am happy that you managed to figure out how to proceed :) For the backup of your configuration, there are a few options (like the rsync). Also, oyou could use a version control system, like for example svn and keep your data there (OK, you need one more "server", but you will have plenty of them with the kvm :) )

Comment: I am hoping to use something like FreeNAS to keep my files on (assuming I can run the FreeNAS as a VM and it can access a RAID at full speed... have to figure that out) I think that would be even better than an svn, right? What are the advantages of using an svn like that for files? I'm already planning to use one for programming stuff. I'll have to look into rsync because I'm really interested in backing up the OS once I have everything set the way I like. And yes, PLENTY of servers now :)

Comment: The biggest advantage is that you can have versions. So, you can rollback to a previous working condition in a few minutes, or even seconds if the need arise!

Comment: I will definitely look into it. I have a lot of data. Pictures, Videos, and I'm a bit of a photography nut at that.. probably close to 300gb already and increasing every weekend ;)
I used svn at school and remember it being relatively slow, but it may have just been the network... and I'm spoiled by 118MBps read speeds(just rewired everything for gigabit)